# CudaMiner - Fail to compile due to nvcc and second error. :D

Tags: 13.10, compiling

```
sarcastic@twitpc:~/CudaM$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sarcastic/CudaM'
Making all in compat
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sarcastic/CudaM/compat'
Making all in jansson
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sarcastic/CudaM/compat/jansson'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sarcastic/CudaM/compat/jansson'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sarcastic/CudaM/compat'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sarcastic/CudaM/compat'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sarcastic/CudaM/compat'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sarcastic/CudaM'
nvcc -g -O2 -Xptxas "-abi=no -v" -arch=compute_10 --maxrregcount=64 --ptxas-options=-v -I./compat/jansson -o salsa_kernel.o -c salsa_kernel.cu
/bin/bash: nvcc: command not found
make[2]: *** [salsa_kernel.o] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sarcastic/CudaM'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sarcastic/CudaM'
make: *** [all] Error 2
sarcastic@twitpc:~/CudaM$
```

I'm a newbie please help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Just enter this command in Terminal. You will see:

```
$ nvcc
The program 'nvcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
You will have to enable the component called 'multiverse'
```

That means you have to install `nvidia-cuda-toolkit`.

Another way is to search in `apt-cache`:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search nvcc
[sudo] password for karimov-danil: 
nvidia-cuda-toolkit - NVIDIA CUDA toolkit
```

The first column in output is the name of the package and the second is description.